# How to get users access token using facepy for facebook application

Tags: python, django, facebook, facebook-graph-api, fandjango

I am using `fandjango` and `facepy` for building facebook application.

So, this is how my code looks.

```
from fandjango.decorators import facebook_authorization_required
from facepy import GraphAPI

@facebook_authorization_required(permissions=["publish_actions"])
def ViewPage (request):
    user_access_token = request.facebook.user.oauth_token
    ....
    profile_id = request.facebook.user.facebook_id
    graph = GraphAPI(access_token)
    og_path = "%d/feed" %profile_id
    ..
    graph.post( path = og_path, og_msg = message )
    ..
```

When I opened the page, it showed `OAuthError`. I search around this website and some mentioned that there would be mistake in `access_token`. When I tried to print the access token on the dev-page, it showed me `Oauth Token Object`.. i.e., its not "access token" (expected "string" object).

So, where am I doing wrong? and how should I fix the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@facebook_authorization_required(permissions=["publish_actions"])
def ViewPage (request):
    user_access_token = request.facebook.user.oauth_token.token
    ....

    graph = GraphAPI(access_token)
```

`request.facebook.user.oauth_token` is `object` type...

```
request.facebook.user.oauth_token.token will give you the access token
```